# How to skip in JSON if one field is not present?

Tags: python

I have JSON file as below, I have to skip `"channels"` which is empty or do not present. How to achieve in python?

```
[
  {
    "account": "fcbc9098c4",
    "name": "test-everything",
    "apps": [
      "messages",
      "kubelet.service"
    ],
    "category": [],
    "viewid": "3fddf26cb4",
    "channels": [
      {
        "integration": "email",
        "immediate": false,
        "terminal": true,
        "triggerlimit": 1,
        "triggerinterval": "30m",
        "operator": "presence",
        "emails": [
          "yugendhar.reddy.jakkidi@****.com"
        ],
        "alertid": "dd317339ad"
      }
    ],
    "presetids": []
  },
  {
    "viewid": "0df42550ee",
    "name": "test - system logs",
    "apps": [
      "kubelet.service",
      "kernel",
      "messages",
      "audit.log",
      "auditd",
      "crio"
    ],
    "category": [],
    "account": "fcbc9098c4"
  }
]
```

I am reading file in python as below...

```
import os
import requests
import json
import sys

filename=open(r"/home/yugendhar.jakkidi/viewsLogdna.json")
data = json.load(filename)
for i in data:
    print(i['name'],i['apps'],i['viewid'])
```

My desired output should be as below, since it has `"channels"`:

```
 {
    "account": "fcbc9098c4",
    "name": "test-everything",
    "apps": [
      "messages",
      "kubelet.service"
    ],
    "category": [],
    "viewid": "3fddf26cb4",
    "channels": [
      {
        "integration": "email",
        "immediate": false,
        "terminal": true,
        "triggerlimit": 1,
        "triggerinterval": "30m",
        "operator": "presence",
        "emails": [
          "yugendhar.reddy.jakkidi@****.com"
        ],
        "alertid": "dd317339ad"
      }
    ],
    "presetids": []
  },
```

Comment: `if "channels" not in obj`?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you are trying to do / how you are trying to read the json.

Comment: @yugreddy, do not write your code in comments, just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68100683/edit) your question and add it.

Comment: Use `.get('channels', [])` and the missing key will be handled like an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition inside your loop

```
for i in data:
    if "channels" in i.keys():
        print(i['name'],i['apps'],i['viewid'])
```

Comment: To check if key is there but empty do it like that if "channels" in i.keys() and len(i["channels"]) > 0:

Answer (score -1):

Try with json list.

```
import os
import requests
import json
import sys

filename=open(r"/home/yugendhar.jakkidi/viewsLogdna.json")
data = json.load(filename)

len = len(data)
n = 0
while n < len:
    try:
        data_channels = data[n]["channels"]
        print(data[n])
    except:
        print("channels not there")
    
    if n ==(len):
        break
    n +=1
```

** output **

```
{
    "account": "fcbc9098c4",
    "name": "test-everything",
    "apps": [
      "messages",
      "kubelet.service"
    ],
    "category": [],
    "viewid": "3fddf26cb4",
    "channels": [
      {
        "integration": "email",
        "immediate": false,
        "terminal": true,
        "triggerlimit": 1,
        "triggerinterval": "30m",
        "operator": "presence",
        "emails": [
          "yugendhar.reddy.jakkidi@ibm.com"
        ],
        "alertid": "dd317339ad"
      }
    ],
    "presetids": []
  }
```